# How to get all document from firebase firestore without giving collection name in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from firebase firestore without collectiion name for data to admin section in my app, I need all document data.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the collection name in your code, use environment variables within Node JS. This should give some further explanation, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/